# SQL Server index options (with) using variable

Tags: sql-server, indexing, sql-server-2019

I would like to create an index and making its options (with) as configurable, example I will take sort_IN_TempDB

```
DECLARE @On NUMERIC(10,2) = 1

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX NCI_TN 
ON Table_Name (Student_ID)
WITH (SORT_IN_TEMPDB = @On)
```

But it throws an error and says the excepted value is Numeric, Integer, ON, or OFF. Is it possible to make options value from variable?

Comment: Not without constructing the entire statement as a string. The T-SQL parser is expecting to find precisely `ON` or `OFF`. Not a variable, not a string, etc.

Comment: Many things in T-SQL don't allow variables, this is one of them (and note that the syntax is `ON` and `OFF`, not `1` and `0`). You'd have to build dynamic SQL and use `EXEC`. However, if someone is clever enough to know what `SORT_IN_TEMPDB` does and can make an educated decision to use it, they should probably also just have permission to run `CREATE INDEX` statements directly, so they wouldn't have to grapple with whatever lovely tooling you're building here.

Comment: Thanks, Building a dynamic query is my last option.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server DDL cannot be parameterized, and in statements that can be parameterized, object identifiers and keywords can't be parameterized.

You'll need to use dynamic SQL, eg

```
DECLARE @On NUMERIC(10,2) = 1

declare @sql nvarchar(max) = concat( N'
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX NCI_TN 
ON Table_Name (Student_ID)
WITH (SORT_IN_TEMPDB = ', case when @On = 1 then 'ON' else 'OFF' end,')')

print @sql
exec (@sql)
```

without dynamic SQL you can use something like

```
DECLARE @On NUMERIC(10,2) = 1

if @On =1 
begin
    CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX NCI_TN 
    ON Table_Name (Student_ID)
    WITH (SORT_IN_TEMPDB = ON)
end
else
begin
    CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX NCI_TN 
    ON Table_Name (Student_ID)
    WITH (SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF)
end
```

Comment: Thanks, Building a dynamic query is my last option

Comment: See updated answer.

Comment: Is `BACKUP` and `RESTORE` considered DDL? Because they can be parameterized

Comment: I think they are commands like DBCC commands, KILL, USE, PRINT, or SHUTDOWN, neither DDL nor DML.